# Does putting an iOS device into single app mode prevent iOS upgrades?

Tags: ios, mobile-device-management

If I set an iOS device into single app mode via MDM, will the iOS update dialog still pop up? Is there a chance that the update can be launched while in single app mode?

Answer (score 2):

We block iOS updates via different ways on our iDevices:

- Via our Firewall, you can block these URLs on your WiFi network : mesu.apple.com, appldnld.apple.com.
- Or you can block WiFi network on your devices via restrictions in a profile pushed by your MDM. So devices will be not able to download iOS updates, but you need to use only 3G/4G.

Answer (score 0):

If you setup single app mode on your iOS device, only those foreground processes are restricted from being showing up. All background processes, including the device downloading the device update, still works. I don't think there'll be pop-ups. If they do, then there is no point setting a device as single app mode because everyone has access to device update feature which *might* turn an app (set up in [single app mode](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-kiosk-software/)) incompatible with new version of iOS. Also consider, if single app mode is managed using an [MDM software](https://www.hexnode.com/mobile-device-management/mobile-device-management-software/) and remote access is not available (just in case) due to incompatibility issue of the MDM, which might be a huge problem.

Anyway, I haven't checked this. I'll keep the answer updated when I do.